# How to access data property of vue component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I think its amazing.  I have been tasked to start implementing some vue components in our non-greenfield web application and I thought I would start by implementing some self-contained "widgets" that have to deal heavily with state in my work's rails app.

Its working great as a self-contained component but I want to load it with a data attribute so the component know what it needs to deal with.  My Vue file looks like (I have redacted parts of this due to IP concerns):

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            ${{ b.id }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg--blue-sky">
            ${{ b.amount }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        errors: [],
        b: {
          id: null,
          amount: null
        }
      }
    },

    // Fetches posts when the component is created.
    created: function () {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/api/b/" + '2' + ".json",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json"
      })
          .then(response => {
            this.b = response.b
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          });
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The component is registered with:

```
import FiDis from '../components/fi_dis.vue'
Vue.component('fi_dis', FiDis);
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const fi_dis = new Vue({
    el: '#bs',
    components: { FiDis }
  })
});
```

And in my html.erb code I create the components with:

```
<div id="bs" policy="2">
    <fi_dis data-b-id="1"></fi_dis>
    <fi_dis data-b-id="2"></fi_dis>
</div>
```

This all works flawlessly, and does exactly what I want it to do except for one thing.  I want to access the data-b-id attribute within the created function of the component (i.e. replace the number '2' in the url of the ajax call above with the value form the attribute).  In this way, I hope for the component to handle ANY "fi_dis" I choose, merely by specifying the b-id in the data attribute I want it to handle.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd do yourself a big favour and seperate all the ajaxing from your component,  at the very least move it into a seperate module

Answer (score 0):

You communicate data values passing [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) from parent component to child components.

So for example you should define which props your component is allowed to receive:

```
import FiDis from '../components/fi_dis.vue'
Vue.component('fi_dis', FiDis);
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const fi_dis = new Vue({
    el: '#bs',
    components: { FiDis },
    props['bId'],
    created() { // This is a lifecycle method
        this.printPropertyValue();
    },
    methods: {
        // Your custom methods goes here separeted by commas
        printPropertyValue() {
            console.log(this.bId);
        }
    }
  })
});
```

And the sintax for passing the data from the component implementation is using `v-bind:propertyName` or `:propertyName` (short hand).

```
<div id="bs" policy="2">
    <fi_dis :bId="1"></fi_dis>
    <fi_dis :bId="2"></fi_dis>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there is no "parent" component? And shouldn't it be props: ['bId']?

Comment: how do you not have a parent component?

Comment: Well v-bind allows you to set javascript variables, so you could perfectly change `v-bind:data-b-id="dataBindId"`.

Comment: Ok, that's working, but how do I access that variable within the context of the created event?  (I can kind of see it in the debugger but i am either calling it wrong or its undefined).

Comment: And in this case `<fi_dis />` is a custom component that is inside a `<div id/>` so it is aumatically a children of a main component.

Comment: I updated my answer, I added how you should access the props via `this`, which points to the *Vue* instance meaning that you can access your properties, local component data, methods and plugins you may defined in your vue compoents (instances).

Comment: Nope, this.bId is 'undefined' its not passing it through from the HTML it seems. The above answer modification doesnt work at all anymore,  `printPropertyValue is not a function).

Comment: Mmm ok, take a look this example I made https://codesandbox.io/s/5xoxro4z54

Comment: I have a comment from your original code, you are mixin up Single File Component structure https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#ad so you should create all your components using that structure. Take a look to the codesandbox example and let me rewrite your code to use that componet structure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: I had a look at your codesandbox example and noticed that it is not solving the issue I want. I want to define the variable from the HTML side.

Comment: You mean from your component tag?, i.e <fi_dis :bId="1"></fi_dis>